# open modal at the bottom of element that opened it

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a modal and a p to open it.

```
  <div class="">
      <div class="modal fade" id="post_wall_feeling_modal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 500px;">
          <div class="modal-content"> 
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal_height_feeling_chosen_activity">
                ......
            </div>                   
          </div>       
        </div>       
      </div> 
</div> 

<p  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#post_wall_feeling_modal' data-whatever='@mdo' />
```

If the modal is opened, it's centered horizontally but I want to show him at the bottom of the element that opended it.

I would like to know if it's possible that the modal be opened near the element that opened it ?

I googled for hours with no results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better use the 'popover', take a look at these bootstraps for example:

https://jsfiddle.net/tom_lima/bjy381zp/3/

They were made just for that purpose, open close to the clicked element. 
In addition you can define wherever it appears with the data-placement parameter

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" title="Dismissible popover" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-html="true"  data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="<b>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.</b>">
    Popover on top
    </button>

    <button type="button"  title="Dismissible popover" class="btn btn-secondary" data-html="true" data-container="body" title="Dismissible popover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
    Popover on right
    </button>

    <button type="button" title="Dismissible popover" data-html="true" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
    sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
    Popover on bottom
    </button>

    <button type="button" title="Dismissible popover" data-html="true" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
    Popover on left
    </button>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
        })
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: I have many code in that modal so I can't use a popover there. The modal is more better .